# Ant replace task corrupts symbols in UTF-8 file

Tags: java, encoding, ant, utf-8

I have the following ant task:

```
<target name="test">
    <replace file="test.txt" token="smth" value="anything"/>        
</target>
```

test.txt is UTF-8 encoded. The problem is that when I run this task
it corrupts some UTF-8 symbols (only few of them, not all).
I've tried to use `ant -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -buildfile=build.xml`,
and specified build.xml encoding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">`,
but the problem remains.

How can I make my Ant task work correctly with UTF-encoded files?

Comment: For example, what is corrupting how?

Comment: Some non-latin symbols, but what particular symbols are corrupted depends on particular computer.

Comment: Why did you delete your comment from my answer? Please answer the questions that I asked in reply to that now-deleted comment.

Comment: Because I realized that it was wrong, but I didn't expected you notice it too fast, so I deleted it, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs for the replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html), in the list of attributes:

> Attribute: encoding
>   Description: The encoding of the files upon which replace operates.
>   Default: No - defaults to default JVM encoding

So it's using the platform default encoding. If you want it to use UTF-8, just change your call to:

```
    <replace file="test.txt" token="smth" value="anything" 
             encoding="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: @tsds: Then it's probably *not* genuinely UTF-8. Where did the file come from, and how are you detecting this corruption? Can you give examples of what has changed in terms of *binary* data? (Open up the file before and after in a hex editor.)

Comment: yes, this worked, thanks. But I've posted the simplified example of ant task that I use (instead of replace I use my custom task), I still can't use your solution for my custom ant task but you gave me a clue.